# How change value in field ActiveForm after click on button?

Tags: php, yii2

How change value `'userid'` in field ActiveForm after click on button?

How it make?

I need to check field `'userid'` and change value.

I not know how it  make.

---

**View:**

_Form.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

?>

<div class="account-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'userid')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-warning' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

Create.php

```
<div class="account-create">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <?= $this->render('_form', ['model' => $model,]) ?>

</div>
```

---

**Controller:**

AccountController.php

```
class AccountController extends Controller
{

public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Account();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post() && $model->save())) {

         return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->userid]);
        } else {

            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

}
```

---

**Model:**

Account.php

```
class Account extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public function rules()
    {

        return [
            [['userid'], 'required']
        ];
    }

}
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I try in Controller - $model->userid;

Comment: unclear what you are asking. elaborate more.

Comment: Insane Skull- in Account.php need change value field 'userid'.

Comment: `userid`  default value or something else? @Пётр

Comment: Insane Skull-  After click button in ActiveForm , need change value in field 'userid'.

Comment: In your controller, use "$model->userid = 1234";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Account();

    if (isset($_POST['Account']){

        $model->attributes = $_POST['Account'];
        $model->userid = 123;

        /* in case you had errors
        // $model->validate();
        // var_dump($model->getErrors());
        */

        if($model->save()){

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->userid]);
        }
    }
    else{

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is for Yii1, in Yii2 `$model->load()` is used instead.